# Встроенные функции пайтон совершенно ПУСТЫЕ, они принимают лишь аргументы! Почему?

Tags: python

кто мне может объяснить, почему когда я перехожу в код встроенных функций пайтона они все просто принимают параметры а в блоке функции всего лишь pass, ДА ОНИ СОВЕРШЕННО ПУСТЫЕ, ОНИ ВЫПОЛНЯЮТ "НИЧЕГО" , НО ВСЕ РАВНО ВЫПОЛНЯЮТ ЧТО-ТО. КАК ПУСТЫЕ ФУНКЦИИ ЧТО-ТО ДЕЛАЮТ, ЭТО ЛОМАЕТ МНЕ МОЗГ

> Вот код функции принт, она пустая, и с другими функциями также:

```
def print(self, *args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None): # known special case of print
    """
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
    
    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
    flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
    """
    pass
```

> Вот еще одно функция:

```
def len(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """ Return the number of items in a container. """
    pass
```

Я беру одни из часто используемых, но все функции одинаковые: только параметры и коммаентарии разные, а в блоке только pass.

Comment: а как и где вы смотрите встроенные функции?

Comment: Может это какой-то базовый класс, а в классе-наследнике эти методы перегружены методами с нормальным телом?

Comment: @strawdog в ИДЕ можно посмотреть как и любую другую функцию - ctrl + левая кнопка мыши.

Comment: Потому что вы смотрите просто какие-то неофициальные аннотации, а настоящие встроенные функции написаны (в случае с CPython) на языке C и вкомпилированы внутрь исполняемых файлов питона

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходный код языка питона - опенсорс, написан на языке C, и [доступен каждому](https://github.com/python/cpython). Код встроенных функции можно посмотреть в файле [bltinmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c).

Для `print()`, я думаю, это будет функция `builtin_print_impl()`.

То, что показывает IDE, это какие-то ей же самой созданные аннотации. Можно увидеть расположению файла. Для Intellij IDEA это примерно

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.2\python_stubs\-1120166012\builtins.py
```

Видно, что это мой профиль пользователя, а не где у меня установлен питон (стандартно в програмфайлс)

Comment: Да спасибо, но у меня linux, наверное это ничего нен меняет, сейчас посмотрю код